# Separate word and add character

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby. Fiddle in http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c9c29

```
# code
term = "123 code ruby"
f_term = term.gsub(/\s/, "% %").insert(0, "%").insert(-1, "%")
puts f_term 

# output
%123% %code% %ruby%
```

How would you refactor my `f_term`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just Use Word Boundaries

Assuming that all you really want to do is surround each word with percent signs, you don't really need to do all those gymnastics with your string. Just use [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) and replace your word boundaries. For example:

```
term = '123 code ruby'
f_term = term.gsub /\b/, '%'
# => "%123% %code% %ruby%"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
term.gsub(/\b/, '%')  # %123% %code% %ruby%
```

Since this uses word boundaries, the behavior is slightly different from yours.  The `/\b/` method will return `%cats%` for the input `cats` where yours would have produced `%% %% %cats% %% %%`